# Form input is overlapping it's container

Tags: html, css

I cannot make that the form input stay all inside his container:
https://codepen.io/Gillispeare/pen/OzYaxJ

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <span>Newsletter</span>
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        <div class="form">
          <form>
            <input type="email" placeholder="insert your email" />
              <a href="#">Submit</a>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family: 'Sedgwick Ave', cursive;
  color: #a1887f
}
a{
  color:inherit;
  outline:none;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor:pointer
}
input{
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline-width: 0;
  border: 2px solid #a1887f;
  &:active,&:focus{
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  }
  &::placeholder{
    color:#a1887f;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-indent: 10px;
  }
}
body{
  background:linear-gradient(-135deg, #e0e0e0, #fafafa);
}
.container{
  width:500px;
  border: 15px solid #a1887f;
  border-radius:10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: linear-gradient(-135deg, #e0e0e0, #fafafa);

}
.box{ 
  perspective:1000px;
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  padding:40px 40px
}
 .back,.box,.front{
      width:100%;
      height:100%
}

.flipper{
  transition:.6s;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
}
.back,.front{
      backface-visibility:hidden
      }
 .front{
      transform:rotateY(0);
   padding:40px 40px;
   background: linear-gradient(-135deg, #e0e0e0, #fafafa);;
   border: 15px solid #a1887f;

    }
    .back{
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;

      border: 15px solid #a1887f;


    display:flex;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
      .form{
        form{
          padding:0 60px !important;
        }
        a{
          position:relative;
          top:5px
        }

      }


          }



    .box:hover .flipper,.box:hover .flipper{
    transform:rotateY(180deg)
  }
```

I tried to set the padding on the form (and his container) but seems doesn't have any effect. it works if I set the width of container and input in px, but I prefer to use some other methods

Comment: The input is perfectly inside the box, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this:

```
.back .form form {
     padding: 0 60px !important; 
}
```

and add `width: 100%` and `display: block` to your input:

```
input {
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline-width: 0;
    border: 2px solid #a1887f;
    width: 100%; //Added line
    display:block //Added line

}
```

Your `padding: 60px` in each side was forcing your display.